# app.yaml working differently on Local and on the Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I've been playing around with GAE for PHP. Here is [my Github code](https://github.com/ProfNandaa/gae-php-explore) and it is running at http://shining-weft-626.appspot.com/

~/form gives me a 404 online but works perfectly on my local machine. Someone help.

Comment: Or is this the proverbial "it was working on my machine"? :)

Comment: put the relevant code in the question, or don't expect too much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/form is (bizarrely) a reserved URL on appengine, you'll have to pick something else: [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Reserved_URLs)

Comment: Noted. Worked after changing to /forms. Thanks @Greg

Answer (score 0):

The URL /form is working fine.

You are getting 404's for the URLs /form/ and /forms, because they do not match anything in your app.yaml.

```
- url: /form
  script: form.php

- url: /
  script: index.php
```

Comment: Thanks sir for the quick response. No, I still get the 404 on this one - http://shining-weft-626.appspot.com/form

Answer (score 0):

You code looks correct, if you committed and pushed it as shown.  I think that you may be getting an error when loading the app.yaml, because you point to directories that do not exist.  Try adding `/js` and `/images` to your `/assets` directory.  They are missing now.  Commit, and push again.

(Or, delete those mappings from your app.yaml)